# Function to find the start and end of conditional selection

Tags: r

I have a `data` that looks as follows:

```
 Date | Time    | Temperature
16995 | "12:00" | 23
16995 | "12:30" | 24
...
17499 | "23:30" | 23
17500 | "00:00" | 24
```

I'm writing a function to select a range of cases based on certain start and end time points. To do this I need to determine the `start_pt` and `end_pt` indices which should match with a pair of rows in the dataframe.

```
    select_case <- function(df,date,time) {
      start_pt = 0
      end_pt = 0
      for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
        if ((date[i] == 17000) & (time[i] == "12:00")) {
            start_pt <- i
            return(start_pt)
        } else {
            next
        }
      }
      for (i in start_pt:nrow(df)) {
        if (date[i] == 17500) {
          end_pt <- i - 1
          return(end_pt)
          break
        } else {
            next
        }
      }
      return(df[start_pt:end_pt,])
    }
```

When I called:

```
test <- select_case(data,data$Date,data$Time)
test
```

I expect the following:

```
 Date | Time    | Temperature
17000 | "12:00" | 23
17000 | "12:30" | 24
...
17499 | "23:00" | 23
17499 | "23:30" | 23
```

Instead i got

```
[1] 1
```

Not sure where i got it wrong here. When I separately ran each of the two for-loops from R console and substituting in the corresponding arguments for each loop, i got the correct indices for both `start_pt` and `end_pt`.

Comment: I don't quite get the logic of the start_pt and end_pt. Are you trying to select fix number of rows or are you interested to subset data based on differing start-date & time?

Comment: Because i think it would be more convenient if i need to apply this same subsetting function over similar datasets in which the Date and Time might be different somehow (incomplete data, for example).
Otherwise i can simply do a subset:

`start <- which((data$Date == 17000) && (test$Time == "12:00"))
end <- tail(which(test$Date == 17499),n=1)
test <- test[start:end,]`

Comment: So are you trying to select a fixed number of rows? Why not put `start_pt` and `end_pt` as the argument of your function?

Comment: In any case, please provide a reproducible example that can replicate your error.

Comment: at  the first `return` executed you will exit the function. Therefore, your function will always exit only returning the index for `start_pt`.

Comment: To exit the for loop as soon as `start_pt` is found you should use `break`

Answer (score 0):

I tried putting each loop in a separate function, named `sta(date,time)` and `end(date)`. Then I bind them in the following function:

```
binder <- function(date,time) {
  return(sta(date,time),end(date))
}
```

and call

```
sta_end <- binder(date,time)
```

I got the error:

```
Error in return(sta(date, time), end(date)) : 
  multi-argument returns are not permitted
```

So i combined them and it worked:

```
binder <- function(date,time) {
      return(c(sta(date,time),end(date)))
    }
sta_end <- binder(date,time)
[1] 1 <an index for end_pt>
```

So the mistake i made in my original function is that i use `return()` 3 times and the function will only return the first one which is `start_pt`. So I took out the first two `return()` and retained the last one:

```
return(df[start_pt:end_pt,])
```

This worked, i got the expected result.